# How to boot from a live cd

Tags: boot, bios

I want to install Ubuntu on my dad's computer. The trouble is his computer will not boot from the live cd. I think the trouble has something to do with the bios. It is an Acer,model number 4520 and currently it has Windows Vista on it. How do you find bios on this computer? Here are some more details about the computer:

120 GB harddrive
64x2 dual core processor
up to 384 MB NVIDIA GetForce

Thank you all in advance for your kind and generous support.

Comment: Can you be more specific, please? The more data you give us, the more we can help.  ... remember having a quite similar problem myself. I have solved it by resetting the BIOS.

Comment: It is generally a matter of resetting the BIOS to boot from the CD/DVD first; approximately like this: http://www.biosdb.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/acer-5560g-bios-boot-settings.jpg

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I am having trouble finding bios on the Acer laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the BIOS and change the boot sequence so that the pc boots from the CD/DVD drive first.

To access the BIOS, you'll need to restart your pc and press a specific key. This key is displayed at the start of the boot process. For example, you may see a message like "Press DEL to enter setup". Press the required key at that time and the BIOS will appear.

You could even simply try different keys, especially DEL and the function keys like F2, F11, F12.